# PHP Google calendar API : delete event

Tags: zend-framework, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to integrate google calendar in my php application. I'm using Zend framework. I managed to add and retrieve events. But deleting events is not working for me. Here is my code (which I copied from a tutorial on IBM )

```
<?php
// load classes
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Calendar');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Http_Client');

// connect to service    
$gcal = Zend_Gdata_Calendar::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME;
$user = "username@gmail.com";
$pass = "pass";
$client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user, $pass, $gcal);
echo 'I m connected ';
$gcal = new Zend_Gdata_Calendar($client);    

// retrieve event
// delete event
try {   


  $event = $gcal->getCalendarEventEntry('http://www.google.com/calendar/
   feeds/default/private/full/xxxxxxxxxxxx');
echo 'eventUrl got';
  $event->delete();
echo 'deleted';
} catch (Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $e) {
  echo "Error: " . $e->getResponse();
}        
echo 'Event successfully deleted!';  
?>
```

Events are not deleted.'eventUrl got' is not printed and the exception isn't caught ! I replaced the xxxxxxx in the getCalendarEventEntry with the cookie that I found in my google calendar (calendar -> settings >URL adress of the calendar-> XML)
What am I doing wrong ?
Thank you for your help

Comment: try adding a second catch for general exceptions, there may be a non Zend_Gdata_App_Exception being thrown.